# Generate Functions Automatically in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm looking to automatically generate functions. For instance, could I make 50 functions named foo1 to foo50 without defining each one?

I'm using this for an interpreter for a domain specific language. Right now, I have about 80 functions that follow this general formula:

```
pqlsymbol * u_greedy_consen(vector<pqlsymbol * > arglist) 
{  
    pqlsymbol * result;
    if (arglist.size() == 1 && arglist[0]->is_treeset()){
        result = new pqlsymbol(greedy_consen(arglist[0]->get_treeset(), 100 ) );
    }
    else if (arglist.size() == 2 && arglist[0]->is_treeset() && arglist[1]->is_double()){
      result = new pqlsymbol(greedy_consen(arglist[0]->get_treeset(), (float)(arglist[1]->get_double()) ) );
    }
    else if (arglist.size() == 2 && arglist[0]->is_treeset() && arglist[1]->is_int()){
      result = new pqlsymbol(greedy_consen(arglist[0]->get_treeset(), (float)(arglist[1]->get_int()) ) );
    }
    else {
        //cout << "consensus expects 1 treeset and optinally 1 Int/Double argument. " << "Found " << get_arg_types(arglist) << endl;
        result = new pqlsymbol(ERROR, "Type Error");
    }
    return result;
}
```

arglist is a list of arguments passed in at the command line. It checks the size of arglist, then check to see if the arguments are of the correct type, and then calls the appropriate function if they are.

So, I want to know if I could reduce this to a more general function. I would give it a vector of what types of arguments are expected and then a pointer to a function that would be called if those arguments are found.

So, is there a way that I could make a call like:

add_function("greedy_consen", [ [treeset], [treeset, int], [treeset, double] ], &greedy_consen)

That would create a function u_greedy_consen which automatically looks for any of the given sets of parameters, and calls greedy_consen with those parameters if found. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at [Terra proggraming language](http://terralang.org), it's much better suited for the task you have at hand. In C++ it would be extremely painful.

Comment: [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) was designed for generating highly redundant functions

Comment: Have you looked into variadic templates yet and whether they can help? They're pretty good code generators.

Comment: You could write a c program to generate the functions for you, perhaps? It would depend on if you had a consistent rule which you could use. Then write to an output file, and use this in your project for compilation? For example, you might want a Pythagoras function (or something like that) for 2, 3, 4 and more dimensions. There is probably a better way of doing something like that though.

Comment: Looks like a regular function template to me.